# PHP: Injection protection using prepared statements

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am familiar with using PHP to perform mySQL queries. However, I have been using reg exps as protection against injection attacks. After reading several questions/answers here on SO, I've decided to opt for prepared statements instead.

There's two options available (let me know if there are more):

1. [mysqli prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
2. [PDO prepared staments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

### Question 1

I am trying to understand the code examples given on the linked pages.

For **mysqli**, Example #1 :

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
```

What does the `"s"` parameter do?
If I need more than 1 paramater, how do I do that?

For **PDO**, Example #1 :

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
```

What is the purpose of `PDO::ATTR_CURSOR` and `PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY` here?

### Question 2

Which one, mysqli or PDO, would you recommend? Pros and cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**

The s parameter binds ":" to whatever value $city has. So if your sql is "`SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name = s`", your executed query would be "`SELECT District FROM City Where Name = $city`".

To bind more parameters, just call [bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) for each parameter. You can also pass an array to PDOStatement::execute.

**Question 2**

Since i use some different databases (mysql and sqllite) i prefer working with PDO. Fore more information on this subject, please refer to [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Answer (score 7):

The `s` indicates that `$city` is expected to be a string

The `PDO::ATTR_CURSOR` part is the name of a setting you are passing to PDO. The value `PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY` (which is the default, so you don't need to specify if) means that for each call you do to `PDOStatement::fetch()` you will be given the next row in the result set. The alternative option would be `PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL` - but unless you specifically know you need this (and your database supports it) you should leave it at the default.