# Inserting email headers into mysql field quotes and slashes issue

Tags: mysql, insert

I am trying to insert email headers read from impap in to a mysql text field. Problem is the headers are full of slashes, commas, quotes, line feeds. mysql_escape doesnt come near it. The different mail server responses can lead to quite different headers. Do i have to do some weird voodoo before storage?

Comment: From the reference to mysql_escape[_string], I assume you are using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**mysql_real_escape_string()**](http://de.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) should really be all you need:

> mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

are you working with multiple connections? If you are, be sure to add `$link_identifier` to the call, as defined in the manual.

Comment: I am a pillock - mysqlescape string does work just fine. Late nights and commas got me fuzzcooed.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements instead of building the query using strings.

See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782650/php-injection-protection-using-prepared-statements).